# Error: Variantoptimizer: No default case found for (qx.debug:off)

Tags: qooxdoo

When trying to generate our application with the variant "qx.debug" set to "on" in the config.json I get a lot of errors like this:

```
Error: Variantoptimizer: No default case found for (qx.debug:off) at (qx.core.Property:1004)
```

I could fix those by adding the "default" cases, but I was wondering, if I was doing something wrong in the first place or if this these are actual issues in the qooxdoo SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, `qx.debug` is set to "on" in the source version by default, so you don't have to do anything for that.

For the build version, you need to configure this in your config.json, e.g. in the "jobs" section add

```
"build" : {
   "variants" : {
       "=qx.debug" : [ "on" ]
   }
}
```

Is this what your config looks like? The error message you gave is weird, which qooxdoo version are you using? You shouldn't need to provide any "default" cases for this variant in the framework code.

Comment: Ah okay, so my configuration was at fault. I was just using "on" as value without the braces.